# Flutter Question: Counter gets brief error after SetState

Tags: reactjs, flutter, widget, counter, setstate

I have a simple app that loads an AlertDialog with 2 IconButtons and a Text in between. ( *<-* *counter* *->* ) .
Every time I press a one of the buttons, I want the counter to increment and decrement.

My simple implementation included :

```
onTap: (){
   setState(() {
        counter++;
   )};
}
```

The problem is that ,although the Text widget containing the counter reloads, for a brief second before the new state appears, there's a red error appearing in the place of the button.

example: [ 4 ] (setState) -> [*err*] -> [ 5 ]

Is this normal ? Do I need a placeholder ? an InitialState ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I have a hunch that your build() method is doing some sort of network traffic, and until the future returns you're in this odd limbo state.

You should treat your build() method as if it can be called 60 times per second, so it should be lightweight and idempotent.